# Using interfaces file - device is not maintained

Tags: networking

I need to set ethtool command at start-up because my router refuse to communicate until I set my LAN card to full duplex mode. I know how to do that using ethtool, but how to preserve changes after reboot?

I've tried editing interfaces file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    pre-up /sbin/ethtool -s $IFACE autoneg off speed 100 duplex full
```

When I do `/etc/init.d/networking restart` everything looks fine, but GNOME says the device is not maintained and I cannot access internet.

What I must change to be able to maintain LAN card using GNOME and use ethtool at boot properly?